# Czech characters encoding in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I need to make a script which parse .htm files.
These .htm files are from a czech website and when opening the file in Notepad, I can see for example the word : Číslo

I first import the source code into a string :

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
```

Then I try to find Číslo in it :

```
$str_init = "Číslo";
$init = mb_strpos($content, $str_init) ;
```

$init returns FALSE...

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you set a file encoding in your editor? Like utf-8 for the file containing the script?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: It is a basic notepad, no such option in it

Comment: @VincentTeyssier If you're on a PC, get yourself a copy of `Notepad++` Here's the link: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ You can then encode to UTF-8 with the BOM or without. Sometimes that's where the problem could be, a `BOM` issue (byte order mark). One never knows ;)

Comment: I have notepad++ and i tried, but the problem has nothing to do with display encoding.

Comment: Číslo is displayed properly in the .htm file.
When I do :
    echo $content;
Číslo is displayed as ÄŒÃ­slo

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Just for the record, I made 2 PHP copies of the same text `Číslo`. The file with the BOM shows it correctly, while the one without the BOM showed up as `CÃ­slo`. Have you tried your file `with` and `without` the BOM to see if it made a difference?

Comment: Well done @Fred !!
With the BOM it works!

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Grrrrreat!! Glad it worked out for you Vincent, cheers ;)

Comment: @VincentTeyssier I'll add it as an answer so that you can close the question and mark it 'answered'. All the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your PHP file `with` the BOM.

Comment: This will make your pages render in Quirks Mode when using IE because `<!DOCTYPE` is not the first bytes in the response anymore. And if you are not using output buffering, you will also get headers already sent errors.