# Cannot make get_file_contents read a cyrillic file names. PHP

Tags: php, urlencode

This is my news.php file:

```
<form action="create_file.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"/>
   <label class="control-label">Заглавие:</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <input name="name" type="text" width="40" class="span6 m-wrap" />
         <input type="submit" value="Продължи..." class="btn red"></input>
      </div>
</form>
```

this is my create_file.php

```
<?php
$pre_file_name = $_POST['name'];

$ext = ".txt";

$file_name = $pre_file_name.$ext;

fopen($file_name,'w');
?>
<form action="edit_file.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"/>
   <label class="control-label">Въведете новината (текст):</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <span class="field"><textarea class="span6 m-wrap" name="edit" cols="1600" rows="10"></textarea></span><p>
         <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>">
         <input class="btn red" type="submit" value="Създай!">
      </div>
</form>
```

This is my edit_file.php:

```
<?php
$edit = $_POST['edit'];

$file_name = $_POST['file_name'];

$file = fopen($file_name, 'w');

fwrite($file,$edit);

fclose($file);

header("Location: news-success.php");



?>
```

delete.php

```
    <?php 
$file = $_GET['name'];
unlink($file);

header('Location: news-delok.php');

?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php
$file_name = $_GET['name'];

$file_read = fopen($file_name,"r");
$contents = fread($file_read, filesize($file_name));
fclose($file_read);


?>
<html>
<form action="edit_file.php" method="POST">
  <label>Title:</label>
  <input class="span6 m-wrap" type="text" placeholder="<?php $array = explode(".",$file_name); echo $array[0] ?>" disabled=""><br>
  <label>Text:</label>
  <textarea class="span6 m-wrap" name="edit" cols="420" rows="10"><?php echo $contents ?></textarea><p>
  <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $file_name ?>">
  <input class="btn red" type="submit" value="Update!">
                            </form>
```

How can I make the script to check if there are spaces in the file name, (for ex. News 1.txt) and to replace them with + (for ex. News+1.txt)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tested it with plain characters? i.e.: English language text?

Comment: Also, consult a similar question asked that I answered and worked > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440105/czech-characters-encoding-in-php

Comment: I have just checked and It is giving me the same with the name of the file: New 1. Can it be because there is &nbsp; (SPACE)?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your entire code. Try deleting (or commenting out) the `space` and re-test.

Comment: One thing I found is that if you're attempting to access the file with an `href`, try with quotes `href='url'` instead of double-quotes. There are many possible reasons this could be happening. Could even be a `BOM` issue, hard to say but don't leave it out of the equation.

Comment: Ok. When the file do not have space, like New1.txt, it is working excellent. I have updated my topic. How can I make the script to check if there are spaces in the file name, (for ex. News 1.txt) and to replace them with + (for ex. News+1.txt)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does it get its name of `New1.txt`?

Comment: Maybe something along the line of `$file_name = preg_replace(' ', '', $file_name);`?

Comment: This could also work `$file_name = preg_replace('/(\s)\s+/', '\\1', $file_name);` Test out both. Can problably use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`.

Comment: Fred, where to paste this: $file_name = preg_replace(' ', '', $file_name);? :)

Comment: After `$file_name = $_POST['file_name'];` I think. In your `edit_file.php`

Comment: You could also replace the `space` with an `underscore` - `_` which might make the files easier to read.

Comment: I added plus in the `preg_replace(' ', '+', $file_name);` so it will replace the space with +, which urlencode read as space :), BUT it is not doing anything. It isn't adding the +. Maybe because we should add it in the create_file.php?

Comment: I'm just going over some of the unaccepted answers. Didn't you try my answer below? Far as I remember, it did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For your **create_file.php** do the following (tested).

For example: If your page title is "**page 1**" with a space between, it will create the page "**page_1.txt**" adding the underscore between. The underscore can be substituted for a "**+**" if required or any other valid character.

```
<?php
$ext = ".txt";
$pre_file_name = $_POST['name'];
$file_name = $pre_file_name.$ext;
$file_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $pre_file_name.$ext);
fopen($file_name,'w');
?>
<form action="edit_file.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"/>
<label class="control-label">Enter the new (text):</label>
<div class="controls">
<span class="field"><textarea class="span6 m-wrap" name="edit" cols="1600" rows="10"></textarea></span><p>
<input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>">
<input class="btn red" type="submit" value="Create one!">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: As you can tell, I translated your language to English. ;-)

Comment: Plus, I don't know quite how your other files are integrated in your news script, but from what I can tell you shouldn't have to modify your other files since once the initial file is created, it gets edited afterwards. Least, that's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

To remove spaces between file name Use **str_replace()**
after following line
`$pre_file_name = $_POST['name'];`

your code will be

```
$pre_file_name = $_POST['name'];

$new_file_name = str_replace(" ", "+", $pre_file_name);
```

Comment: And than what, I'm replacing the following ` $file_name = $pre_file_name.$ext;
fopen($file_name,'w'); `

Comment: what is your question ? actually i thought your asking about replacing spaces with + . because of that i suggest to use that code in **create_file.php**

Comment: execute this code you will get your answer
`<?php
$tmp="go to";
$new = str_replace(" ", "+", $tmp);
echo $new;
?>`

Comment: No it works great thank you, but my delete.php, edit.php, edit_file.php, doesn't work. I guess that I should fix sth there too. :) I'll add their content in the main topic above.

Comment: I added the same line you gave me in the other script and changed few variables. :)